# How to specify JAXBContext implementation in weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: xml, jaxb, weblogic

I have created a MDB in java using JAXB to parse the xml content. 
This MDB is working from a long time now (about 3 years) on a 10.3.4 weblogic server.

Now I've to migrate it on a weblogic 12.1.3 server, and for a reason I'm not knowing yet, the implemention choose by weblogic isn't the same as I want. But I can't figure out how to set it.

Right now my code init code is this :

```
private JAXBContext getJAXBContext() throws JAXBException {
    if (v1JaxbContext == null) {
       v1JaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
    }
    System.out.println("jaxbContext : "+v1JaxbContext.getClass().getName());
    return v1JaxbContext;
}
```

MyClass.java is generated by JAXB from an XSD.

On my eclipse the output is **com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl**

On my weblogic side the ouput is **org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i was using my code through an EAR I had to put these lines :

```
<wls:prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext</resource-name>
</wls:prefer-application-resources>
```

And create the file in the META-INF directory of my EAR **services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContex** which contains only, and it works

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and worked out similar solution which doesn't require creating a new file:

`<prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>javax.xml.bind.*</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>`